# Selecting count(column) from different table

Tags: mysql

I have three tables area,vehicle and employee.
ward_no is the foreign key for vehicle and employee.
I want to select the number of vehicles and number of employees and display them along with other details of area.
The query i used is:

```
select a.* ,count(v.vid) as vehicles,count(e.eid) as employees from area a,vehicle v,employee e where v.ward_no=a.ward_no and e.ward_no=a.ward_no group by a.name;
```

But the output is not what I want. I get the same values in both the columns where the count is use instead of displaying the total number of vehicles/employees in that particular area.
I'm new to MySQl

Comment: What did you try, what did you get, what did you expect to get? Please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior of `count` is to count the non-null values.
In your case, this counts repetitions of the value.

Try adding `DISTINCT` inside the count:

```
    select a.* ,count(DISTINCT v.vid) as vehicles,count(DISTINCT e.eid) as employees 
    from area a,vehicle v,employee e 
    where v.ward_no=a.ward_no and e.ward_no=a.ward_no group by a.name;
```

Also, it's better to use explicit JOIN rather than implicit, like this:

```
select a.* ,count(DISTINCT v.vid) as vehicles,count(DISTINCT e.eid) as employees 
    from area a JOIN vehicle v ON v.ward_no=a.ward_no 
    JOIN employee e ON e.ward_no=a.ward_no
    group by a.name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!

Answer (score 1):

There may be a chance that you are getting same vehicle and employee multiple times due to the joins, Use `DISTINCT` in `COUNT()` get count of unique vehicles and employees

```
SELECT 
  a.*,
  COUNT(DISTINCT v.vid) AS vehicles,
  COUNT(DISTINCT e.eid) AS employees 
FROM
  `area` a 
  JOIN vehicle v 
    ON v.ward_no = a.ward_no 
  JOIN employee e 
    ON e.ward_no = a.ward_no 
GROUP BY a.name
```